# Can I throw out source code after running setup.py?

Tags: python, installation, biopython

I'm new to installing python packages.

I just installed Biopython by going to the source code (downloaded from github) and running:

```
python setup.py build
```

My question is - can I now throw out the source code files (in folder) on my desktop? Or do I have to keep them there for the Biopython package to work?

Comment: Say you're not sure, why not move the files to a different folder, check that everything's working, and in case not - return the files back to their original place. Makes sense ?

Comment: `python setup.py build` doesn't install anything... it simply builds the package.  You would need to call `python setup.py install`.  _That_ command will copy the files to your Python "site-packages" folder.  After that, you can remove the files from your desktop.

Comment: Thank you! I did the install command and it looks like everything was written to the site-packages folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, but likely not.

If you were to *install* it, like this:

```
python setup.py install
```

… then you could throw away the whole source directory. That's exactly what `pip` does, in effect. (Speaking of `pip`, for most packages, it's better to use `pip` to install them. That way you can, for example, uninstall them, or upgrade them, or list them out so you know what you had installed before upgrading Python or moving to a new machine. The main exception is, of course, packages that don't work with `pip`, which you'll discover when you try and it fails.:)

But if all you did was *build* it, so you can run it from within its own directory, any top-level scripts aren't compiled, other modules may be compiled but may still expect to find source somewhere, etc. (Of course you can always test and see—back up the directory, delete all the `.py` files, try it, and if it doesn't work, restore the backed up copy…)